# Which preposition to use when "going to ATM"?

Tags: preposition

I am confused between `in ATM` or `zum ATM` when I want to say that I am going to the ATM.

Comment: It might help if tell us what you mean with "ATM". Is it the physical unit to measure air pressure? Is it Adobe Type Manager, or Asynchronous Transfer Mode? There is even a sexual practice that is abbreviated as ATM.

Comment: From the context it seems clear to me that he's referring to what we Austrians call _Bankomat_ (and the Germans _Geldausgabeautomat_, I suppose).

Comment: Your question makes no sense, because “zum” is German, and ”ATM” is American, so “zum ATM” is not an expression in any language to begin with.

Comment: Why on earth would you use "in"? It's not "in" in English and in any other language I know. Trust your common sense more.

Answer (score 8):

Definitely *zum*, but of course you must translate ATM as well.

> Ich gehe zum Geldautomaten.

Comment: I would definitely use the uninflected _Geldautomat_ in colloquial speech. YMMV.

Comment: You are not the only one to do so, but even in colloquial speech I prefer "Geldautomaten", too. Additionally "zum" stands for "zu dem" and since the article is already inflected, you should inflect the noun, too, shouldn't you? YMMV, but uninflected it is just wrong.

Comment: Well, it's definitely on its way out, at least in Austria. The way we don't use -e in dative anymore (dem Volk**e**, e.g.) -en will be gone within a generation or so as well.

Comment: You make me weep. I like, almost love, that German can be used so precisely and you give such a foretelling.... :-(  I know you are right generally. We do simplify the use where we can, if we want to or not. Especially influenced by English. IMHO

Comment: @Daniel in what way does omitting the -en makes German less precise?

Comment: @clinch My last comment was about omitting things in general. When we happen not to distinguish, if we could, but it is not needed, that's fine. In my experience this habit spreads so even if we should, we often do not distinguish. e.g. the differences of 'wenn', 'falls' and 'sobald'. Although these words share meanings. I prefer using a language more precisely, even if not needed, to the same habit the other way round. Once you get used to a habit, it sticks around. I know that painfully. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Or "an den" - "Ich gehe an den Geldautomaten, um Geld abzuheben" = "I´m going to the ATM to get money"

Comment: Warum zum ??? I m going to ATM machine for money  in this case action is going on so for action we use akusative case then how we can use zum

Comment: Zum is the way you use it in everyday language. But I think the way i wrote it is the right way you would write it.

Comment: @MonaDh: The preposition "zu" requires dative case.

Comment: @MonaDh Die Frage nach dem Ort ist, wohin gehst Du? nicht jedoch, Wen oder Was gehst Du? Wen oder was wäre die Frage nach dem Akkusativ Objekt. Hier muss eine Adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes (Richtung) benutzt werden. "... an den Geldautomaten" ist also auch kein Akkusativ sondern mit "an" gebildet, was den Akkusativ fordert, "zu" jedoch fordert den Dativ, wie **npit** schon kommentierte. Die Fragen wären, "An wen/was gehst Du? oder "Zu wem gehst Du?". Wie gesagt beides Fragen nach der Richtung, also adverbiale Bestimmung.